# How to pass argument to function without getting called javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var function1 = function (ans){
  alert("A");
}
$(document).ready({
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function1(ans));
});
```

If `function1` has no parameter then we can just have `.click(function1)` and `function1` will not be called.

Meanwhile, when there is a parameter, `function1` is called immediately when document is loaded. How to pass a parameter to a function without having the function called ?

Comment: `.click(function() { function1(ans); })`.

Comment: `var function1 = function (ans){
          return function() {
              alert("A",ans);
          }
        }
        $(document).ready({
          $("input[type='radio']").click(function1(ans));
        });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a `callback` function:

```
$(document).ready({
   $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
         function1(ans));
   });
});
```

`$("input[type='radio']").click(function1(ans));` triggers the `click` event handler `automatically`.

Comment: Ohh so we need to call it inside another function. Thank you!